# Get resources folder path c#

Tags: c#, path

Some resources I have in my project are fine and working Ok using string paths but what if I move the project to another directory or to another computer, it will stop working.

Please I need to get the path of the resources folder of my project in a string variable,

Something like this

```
C:\Users\User1\Documents\<projects folder>\<project name>\Resources\
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you access the resources in code?

Comment: @crea7or Im just using the path of my project, to display an image in a PictureBox by example: pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\Isaac\OneDrive\Proyectos\Proyecto Final Solucion\BD Clases\Proyecto Final\Resources\Terreno\0.jpg";

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` returns the path `C:\Users\Isaac\Documents`, then and you can concatenate it with the later part of your folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the files are stored in your project folder, you can retrieve the files using 
`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`. 
This statement retrieves the path as to where your application is installed. 
Click [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a detailed explanation on this.

Answer (score 20):

If you know the path relative to where the app is running, you can do something like this.
First, get the app's running path:

```
string RunningPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Then, get navigate to the relative path using something like this:

```
string FileName = string.Format("{0}Resources\\file.txt", Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(RunningPath, @"..\..\")));
```

In this example I my "Resources" folder is located two directories up from my running one.

I should also mention, that if your resource is included in the project, you should be able to get it using:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

this will return an array of your resources.

Comment: I use the `GetManifestResourceNames();` method and it just returns `MyProject.g.resources` and `MyProject.Properties.Resources.resources`...  Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the cleanest way, but it has been useful to me.

If you had a structure like:

```
C:\...\MyApp\app.exe
C:\...\MyApp\ConfigFiles\MyConfig.xml
```

The code will return a path relative to the running assembly.

```
GetPath("ConfigFiles/MyConfig.xml") // returns the full path to MyConfig.xml

private string GetPath(string relativePath)
{
    var appPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string pattern = @"^(.+\\)(.+exe)$";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
    var match = regex.Match(appPath);
    return System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(match.Groups[1].Value + relativePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use |DataDirectory| documented [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.datadirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's a description of how it works from [an old Microsoft article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx)

> One of the reasons why it was hard to work with database files before
>   is that the full path to the database was serialized in different
>   places. This made it harder to share a project and also to deploy the
>   application. In this version, the .NET runtime added support for what
>   we call the DataDirectory macro. This allows Visual Studio to put a
>   special variable in the connection string that will be expanded at
>   run-time. So instead of having a connection string like this:
>
> ```
>   "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFileName=c:\program files\app\data.mdf"
> ```
>
> You can have a connection string like this:
>
> ```
>   "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\data.mdf"
> ```
>
> This connection string syntax is supported by the SqlClient and OleDb
>   managed providers.
>
> By default, the |DataDirectory| variable will be expanded as follow:
>
> ```
>   - For applications placed in a directory on the user machine, this will be the app's (.exe) folder.
>   - For apps running under ClickOnce, this will be a special data folder created by ClickOnce
>   - For Web apps, this will be the App_Data folder
> ```