# data source folder on other device

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

we have data stored in an Excel file (Trail_Test.xls), which is stored in the Resources folder of our C# project.
now we need to load data from that xls file to dataGridView on the windows form application we have.

This is the code we use

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Resources\Trail_Test.xls";
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [20$]", MyConnection);
DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
```

This gives an error on the 8th line:

The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '20$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

any help ??

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path has to be relative to the executable. For example if the executable is in

```
C:\Users\Adham\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Curve Fitting\Curve Fitting\
```

then the path to the .xls file will be

```
string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Resources\Trail_Test.xls";

string connectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
```

Comment: @ Slai Great, this is exactly what we wanted, thanks

Comment: use `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead because `GetFullPath` depends on the current directory.

Comment: @ Slai the question have been edited according to the new code

Comment: Did it work before with `string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"Resources\Trail_Test.xls");` ?

Comment: That was just an example. On the other device the path can be different depending on where the executable is. Post the full path to the executable and the .xls file on the other device for updated example.

Comment: @ Slai when the project is published it gives a folder containing (Application Files "folder" , Curve Fitting "Application manifest", setup.exe) this folder is copied to the other device on the desktop and installed

Comment: @ Slai the other device doesn't have the .xls file, isn't it included in the published folder as it was in the project resources folder before publishing??

Comment: Ok i've tried that. Now the xls file is included in the published folder in Application Files folder under the name "Trail_Test.xls.deploy" inside folder called Resources. But when executing it on another device still gives an error meaning its not a valid path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118849/discussion-between-user3332603-and-slai).

Comment: @ Slai when using `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` it gives a strange path on the other device, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Your MyConnection object includes

> Data Source='C:\Users\Adham\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Curve Fitting\Curve Fitting\Resources\Trail_Test.xls

that looks like something that should not be hardcoded and will cause problems when executed on any other computer but Adham's.

Comment: I agree, then how to fix these problems caused when executed on any other computer but Adham's.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Make sure that the file is marked as "Copy to output directory=copy if newer", just right click on it and see "properties"

Answer (score 0):

you should reach the installition folder. It will depends on your project type. There is an answer to reach Resources folder for a c# project

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27182028/3209523